# Query to list users who have answered similarly to questions as the specified user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a project in which users answer questions with yes/no choices and an option of must-match, e.g.:
Question 1) Stack Overflow is helpful? [Yes / No] [MustMatch]
Question 2) Hills are better than beaches? [Yes / No] [MustMatch]
etc.
Users can skip questions if they want.

**I need MySQL query to calculate match percentage or match ratio between two specified users; the match ratio being number of same answers / number of common questions.** (The MustMatch option should be ignored for this query.) Example:
User 3 has answered as: Q1) Yes, Q2) No, Q3) Skip, Q4) Yes
User 5 has answered as: Q1) Yes, Q2) Yes, Q3) No, Q4) Yes
User 9 has answered as: Q1) Yes, Q2) No, Q3) Yes, Q4) No
Suppose we want match ratio of user 3 and user 5. The match ratio will be same-answers / common-questions = 2/3 as they have answered same to 2 questions (Q1 and Q4) and because user 3 skipped a question so they have 3 questions in common.
If we want match ratio of user 5 and user 9, it'll be 1/4.

**I also need MySQL query to show top 20 matches in descending order of match ratio for a user.** The MustMatch option should be considered for this query. This list of top 20 matches will contain userid, no. of common answers, no. of common questions and (match percentage or match ratio). For top 20 matches of example user 5: user 3 will come before user 9 in descending order of match ratio:

```
UserID CommonAnswers CommonQuestions Percentage  
...  
3           2             3             66%  
...  
9           1             4             25%  
...
```

"MustMatch" explained:
Simply, the answer must match. If the answer to a question is important compatibility match to a user then they can mark their answer as MustMatch. If a user marks their answer as MustMatch and that particular answer doesn't match with the other user then don't show their match in top 20 list of either of the users.
For example, if user 5 marks their answer to the 4th question as MustMatch then in user 5's top 20 list, user 9 won't display because of mismatching answers to 4th question. Also then in user 9's top 20 list, user 5 won't display.
If user 5 marks their answer to the 3rd question as MustMatch then user 5 won't match with user 3 as user 3 has skipped that question and user 5 won't match with user 9 because of mismatching answers to that question.
Skipped question can't be marked MustMatch, as you can see in below database design that it's not possible.

This is my table for storing answers:

```
create table `answers`(
`userid` mediumint unsigned not null,
`qid` tinyint unsigned not null, # question id
`answer` bit(1) not null,
`mustMatch` bit(1) not null default b'0',
primary key (`userid`,`qid`)
);
```

If a question is skipped then don't have its record in this answers table.

I've a separate table for storing questions' texts:

```
create table `questions`(
`qid` tinyint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`question` tinytext not null
);
```

In calculating top 20 matches, apart from MustMatch, there's another factor: "MinMatch", in which users can set the minimum matching answers they want from their matches. If user 5 set their MinMatch as 3 then in top 20 list of any user, user 5 will match with only those users who have minimum 3 same answers as user 5. MinMatch is set by the user; it should be >=1 and <= total questions answered by the user.

```
create table `users`(
`userid` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`minMatch` tinyint unsigned default 1 # minimum matching answers
);
```

Can you please tell how to make the two queries? (my two bolded sentences)

Here's how the 2nd query may be: (you can skip this)

```
SELECT
    U2.userid,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN A1.answer = A2.answer THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS common_answers,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN A1.answer IS NOT NULL AND A2.answer IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS common_questions,
    common_answers/common_questions AS ratio
FROM
    questions Q
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers A1 ON
    A1.qid = Q.qid AND
    A1.userid = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers A2 ON
    A2.qid = A1.qid AND
    A2.userid <> A1.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN users U2 ON
    U2.userid = A2.userid
GROUP BY
    U2.userid
ORDER BY
    ratio DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Here i've modified someone(Tom H)'s query i found on Stack Overflow for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320306/how-do-i-write-a-function-to-compare-and-rank-many-sets-of-boolean-true-false). But my this query doesn't work (error: `Unknown column 'common_answers' in 'field list'`) and doesn't include the MustMatch and MinMatch factors.

---

*More edit: (More explanation:)*

How my first example is stored in the database:
`answers` table:

```
userid qid answer mustMatch
    3   1   1       0
    3   2   0       0
    3   4   1       0
    5   1   1       0
    5   2   1       0
    5   3   0       0
    5   4   1       0
    9   1   1       0
    9   2   0       0
    9   3   1       0
    9   4   0       0
```

As discussed, match ratio of user 3 and user 5 = 2/3, match ratio of user 5 and user 9 = 1/4.
Let's add a new user: User 4:
User 4 has answered as: Q1) Yes, Q2) No, Q3) No, Q4) Yes

```
userid qid answer mustMatch
    4   1   1       0
    4   2   0       0
    4   3   0       0
    4   4   1       0
```

Let's start calculating top 20 but before that we need to know the users' minMatch values:
`users` table:

```
userid minMatch
    3   1
    5   1
    9   1
    4   1
```

Top 20 matches of user 5:
Result:

```
UserID CommonAnswers CommonQuestions Percentage
    4       3               4           75%
    3       2               3           66%
    9       1               4           25%
```

If user 5 marks their answer to 3rd question as must match, i.e. this record:

```
userid qid answer mustMatch
    5   3   0       0
```

changes to this:

```
    5   3   0       1
```

Then user 5's top 20 list will be:

```
UserID CommonAnswers CommonQuestions Percentage
    4       3               4           75%
```

Because only user 4 matches with user 5's answer to 3rd question.
Also then user 3's top 20 list will be:

```
UserID CommonAnswers CommonQuestions Percentage
    4       3               3           100%
    9       2               3           66%
```

Now if user 9 increases their min match to 3, i.e. this record:

```
userid minMatch
    9   1
```

changes to this:

```
    9   3
```

Then user 3's top 20 list will be:

```
UserID CommonAnswers CommonQuestions Percentage
    4       3               3           100%
```

User 9 got removed from user 3's top 20 list, because user 3 and user 9 have only 2 answers in common while user 9 requires minimum 3 answers to be in common.
Also then user 9's top 20 list will be empty as no user has at least 3 matching answers with user 9.

---

Instead of storing answers as i'm storing now, i can store them as strings in the `users` table if that's a better method. Adding a field `answers` to the `users` table:

```
create table `users`(
`userid` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`minMatch` tinyint unsigned default 1, # minimum matching answers
`answers` char(5) not null default 'sssss' # 5 questions
);
```

Then answers can be stored as strings e.g. yYNns, where y=yes to 1st and 2nd questions in this string, n=no to 3rd and 4th questions, capitalizations to 2nd and 3rd questions ('Y' and 'N') means must match, s=skip the 5th question.

Or maybe some other better storage method. You can give me the 2 SQL queries according to whichever method you think is the best.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Aren't my examples enough?

Comment: They are very hard to follow because the data is not presented in a tabular format.  They also lead directly to the issue:  what if two users have only one question in common?  Do you really want 0% or 100%?

Comment: @GordonLinoff One question in common and the two users have answered the same = 1/1 = 100% match. Problem is when no question in common because that's 0/0, i want no question in common to be 0% match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've followed your suggestion by adding "More edit: (More explanation:)" section to my question. You can check it out. Also i've started a bounty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part where you just want to get the ratio of equally answered questions to common answered questions, I'd use this query:

```
select a1.userid, a2.userid, sum(a1.answer = a2.answer) / count(*) as ratio
from answers a1
join answers a2 on a2.qid = a1.qid and a2.userid > a1.userid
group by a1.userid, a2.userid
order by a1.userid, a2.userid;
```

I am using `a2.userid > a1.userid` to get each user pair only once. (If I used `a2.userid <> a1.userid`, I'd get users 3 and 5 twice for instance, one time as 3/5 and one time as 5/3.)

If you want to look up two particular users, we add the appropriate `WHERE` clause and remove `and a2.userid > a1.userid`. We can also get rid of `GROUP BY`, because there is just one row to return.

```
select sum(a1.answer = a2.answer) / count(*) as ratio
from answers a1
join answers a2 on a2.qid = a1.qid
where a1.userid = 3 and a2.userid = 5;
```

For the top 20 query we have one user given and need a `HAVING` clause to make sure no mustmatch and minmatch is violated.

```
select
  a1.userid,
  a2.userid,
  count(*) as common_questions,
  sum(a1.answer = a2.answer) as common_answers,
  sum(a1.answer = a2.answer) / count(*) as ratio
from answers a1
join answers a2 on a2.qid = a1.qid and a2.userid <> a1.userid
where a2.userid = 9
group by a1.userid, a2.userid
having sum(a1.answer <> a2.answer and (a1.mustmatch = 1 or a2.mustmatch = 1)) = 0
and sum(a1.answer = a2.answer) >=
      all (select minmatch from users u where u.userid in (a1.userid, a2.userid))
order by ratio desc
limit 20;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21edc084a0843987a14cb8b49f0f0213

Both queries use `sum( <boolean expresssion> )`. As true is 1 and false is 0 in MySQL this counts matches. The standard SQL way of writing this would be `sum(case when <boolean expresssion> then 1 else 0 end)` or `count(*) filter (where <boolean expresssion>)`.

Comment: Thanks. For the first query, i just want match ratio of two users already given, e.g. matchRatio(3,5) = 2/3. Don't want table of match ratio of every user vs every other user for the first part, only a single pair of users whose userids will be specified in the query. For the second part, can you please also include the "MinMatch" factor i've talked about in my question? The `minMatch` field goes in the `users` table.

Comment: Okay. For the first query this is extrmely simple: `<` becomes `<>` and we need a where clause on users, just as in the second query. As to the second query: This is also very simple, as this is just a condition to be added to the having clause. In my example where I look for matches of user #9: Must I consider user 9's minMatch or the other user's minMatch or both?

Comment: minMatch of both users should be considered. Please update the two queries in your answer so that i can accept your answer. Also, as i want to output number of common_answers and number of common_questions along with the ratio, can i have something like select a1.userid, a2.userid, sum(a1.answer = a2.answer) as common_answers, count(*) as common_questions, common_answers/common_questions as ratio ...?

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer accordingly. Yes, your expressions for common_questions and common_answers are correct. You cannot use these aliases in the same `SELECT` clause, though.

Comment: You've answered both my questions. An optimization question: In the updated first query, the query where we're calculating match ratio of a given pair, is " and a2.userid <> a1.userid" required? I removed it and the edited query seems to be working fine too.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, I tried to break it up into many steps for clarification.

Please note we choose here userid 5 as the base user to compare to him all the rest. This can be changed easily in `user1` and `user2` cte table:

```
WITH 
answers (userid, qid, answer, must_match) AS
(
  VALUES ROW(3,1,'y',false), ROW(3,2,'n',false), ROW(3,3,'s',false), ROW(3,4,'y',false), 
         ROW(5,1,'y',false), ROW(5,2,'y',false), ROW(5,3,'n',false), ROW(5,4,'y',true), 
         ROW(9,1,'y',false), ROW(9,2,'n',false), ROW(9,3,'y',false), ROW(9,4,'n',false)
),
user1 AS -- the desired user
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM answers 
 WHERE userid = 5
  AND answer != 's'
),
user2 AS -- all the rest of users
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM answers 
 WHERE userid != 5
  AND answer != 's'
),
join_t AS
(
 SELECT user1.qid qid, user2.userid u2_id, 
        user1.answer = user2.answer answers_match,
        ( user1.must_match OR user2.must_match ) AND ( user1.answer != user2.answer ) breaks_match
 FROM user1 
 JOIN user2
  ON user1.qid = user2.qid
),
count_t AS
(
 SELECT u2_id,
        count(*) common_questions,
        count(case when answers_match then 1 end) same_answers,
        max(breaks_match) breaks_match
 FROM join_t
 GROUP BY u2_id
),
ratio_t AS
(
  SELECT u2_id userid,
         same_answers, 
         common_questions,
         concat(same_answers, '/', common_questions, ' = ') r,
         round( (same_answers / common_questions) * 100, 2) as ratio,
         breaks_match
  FROM count_t
)
SELECT * 
FROM ratio_t
WHERE not breaks_match
ORDER BY ratio DESC
LIMIT 20
;
```

This of course answers the second question (that is more general).

For answering the first question, just change the last select with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ratio_t
WHERE userid = 9
;
```

Link to try: https://paiza.io/projects/e/5vyWa_aUb-zK8MQ4N7x3Kg

Answer (score 1):

A direction to consider...  Have a bit string.  Have 3 bits per question, one for each of Yes/No/Skip.  Then count the number of identical responses via:

```
BIT_COUNT(user1.bits & user2.bits)
```

Before MySQL 8.0, `BIGINT UNSIGNED` holds 64 bits, hence handling up to 21 questions in one table column.  For more questions, break into multiple bigints.  With `BIGINT`, `1 << n` gives a mask for bit #n (n=0..63).  That can be or'd (via operator `|`) to set a bit.  Other operations are almost as easy.

For 8.0, `BLOB` can handle bit operations, thereby allowing an essentially unlimited number of questions in a single column.

An optimization:  2 bits per question: one for Yes, one for No.  Skip is indicated by both bits being 0.  The `BIT_COUNT(...)` works as described above.